# How to replace Swagger UI header logo in Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using the Swashbuckle package for WebAPI and am attempting to customize the look and feel of the swagger ui default page.
I would like to customize the default swagger logo/header. I have added the following to SwaggerConfig

```
.EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
 {
  c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, 
    typeof(SwaggerConfig).Namespace + ".SwaggerExtensions.custom-js.js");
  }
```

The contents of custom-js.js are as follows:

```
$("#logo").replaceWith("<span id=\"test\">test</span>");
```

This works for the most part but the visual is a bit jarring, in that the default swagger header is visible while the page loads and after a brief delay the jquery below kicks and the content of the #logo element is updated

Is there a way to avoid this so that the jquery kicks in as part of the initial load/render and it appears seamless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adding a new "index.html" based off [this version](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/v5.2.1/Swashbuckle.Core/SwaggerUi/CustomAssets/index.html)
instead of trying to modify the behavior of the default generated one

Comment: sir, please help where I need to put this "index.html" in my asp.net mvc or asp.net core web api project.

Answer (score 22):

Here are the steps instead of using the index.html

**Step 1:**
Create your logo en put it into a folder, in my case I created a separate folder(I am not using the `wwwroot`) and I named **Content**. Use StaticFiles for stream content from this folder access via `/Content`

```
app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder if you need it
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Content")),
    RequestPath = "/Content"
});
```

**Stem #2:**
Create an `image` folder inside `Content` and place your `logo.jpg` file. Right-click over the file and change the Build Action to **Embedded resource**

[image]

**Step #3:**
Create a `css` folder inside `Content` and place a new file `swagger-mycustom.css` and change the Build Action to `Content`

[image]

On your `Startup` `Configure` method add this code

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(setupAction =>
{
    ....
    setupAction.InjectStylesheet("/Content/css/swagger-mycustom.css");
    ...
}
```

**Step #4:**
Add this to your css:

```
img[alt="Swagger UI"] {
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    content: url('/Content/images/logo.jpg');
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I recommend using EmbeddedFileProvider instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44120595/3115559

Comment: I will give it a try when I have a chance and will update the answer, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Under wwwroot you don't need to change the build action, just add the content. And you don't need that special folder, so the url for the logo would be "/images/logo.png"

Comment: You are  correct. In my solution I had it with this structure and I was not grouping it as part of the wwwroot

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me with the last version of Swagger UI in Swashbuckle

```
.swagger-ui img {
     content: url([logo_path]);
     width: 140px; /* width of your logo */
     height: 40px; /* height of your logo */
}
```

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: Works for me as well. I even use data:image/jpeg;base64 css url path. Hide swagger branding .swagger-ui .topbar span {
    display: none;
}

Answer (score 6):

To replace logo in swagger in api for .net core, you have to add the custom.js file.

Follow below steps to change logo.

Step 1 - Create custom.js file and add following code in it

```
(function () {
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {

        var logo = document.getElementsByClassName('link');

        logo[0].children[0].alt = "Logo";
        logo[0].children[0].src = "/logo.png";
    });
}); })();
```

Step 2 - Inject thar custom.js file in startup.cs file. See below

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.InjectJavascript("/custom.js");

        });
```

Step 3 - Enable static file in the api if not enabled. Add below line of code in Configure method of startup.cs.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: Worked for me just now, thanks! here's how it looks for me: https://github.com/rswag/rswag/issues/616#issuecomment-1493073432

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to create the index.html, you can also update the logo with injected css, this is a lot faster than js injection.

In swagger config enable the c.InjectStylesheet and point to the css you created

In the css itself:

```
.logo__img {
 background: url([PathToLogo]) no-repeat;
 display: block;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 64px; /* Width of new image */
 height: 25px; /* Height of new image */
 padding-left: 64px; /* Equal to width of new image */
}
```

credits for css trick:
https://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/

Answer (score 2):

@MichaelD can simply do the following instead:

```
.logo__img {
    content: url([PathToLogo]);
    width: 72px; /* Width of new image */
    height: 31px; /* Height of new image */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom-js.js need to be placed after all js file.