# Serve Static Files from External Library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I was trying to serve static files that was inside an external library.

I'm already do to work Controller and Views, but i'm not able to load the resources (javascript, images, ...) from that library.

Here is my Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    //...
    var personAssembly = typeof(PersonComponent.Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var personEmbeddedFileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(
          personAssembly,
          "PersonComponent"
       );

     services
       .AddMvc()
       .AddApplicationPart(personAssembly)
       .AddControllersAsServices();

    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.FileProviders.Add(personEmbeddedFileProvider);
                });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //...
        var personAssembly = typeof(PersonComponent.Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var personEmbeddedFileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(
            personAssembly,
            "PersonComponent"
        );

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        //This not work
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(
                personEmbeddedFileProvider
            )
        });
    }
```

And here my buildOptions settings on project.json of External Library:

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "embed": [
      "Views/**/*.cshtml",
      "wwwroot/**"
    ]
  },
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Thank you all (and sorry my bad english)

Comment: Could be due to to the fact, that your resources are inside wwwroot folder. Try moving its content to the root of your external ibrary

Comment: That's worked for me! Thanks! 

But i'm still looking for an alternative without moving content to the root, because i want to use Bower for external plugins. 

Anything I post again

Comment: I don't think its possible, w/o writing your own provider. `EmbeddedFileProvider` doesn't seem to support a root path where it looks like https://github.com/aspnet/FileSystem/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical/PhysicalFileProvider.cs#L39 This root path is set for the `PhysicalFileProvider` to `wwwroot`, because the request middleware is unaware where the file is located. When you use the middleware, only the path w/o the `wwwroot` is passed to the middleware.

Comment: You could try the constructor overload with the namespace overload, but i doubt it will work and likely break views

Comment: Also its bad idea anyways to store the packages within a class library. Typically you use npm or bower to restore it after deployment or while creating of the docker container

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know this is an old question but i faced the same problem and for me the solution was to create the embedded file provider passing as parameters the external assembly and a string like **"assemblyName.wwwroot"**.

Assuming that your assembly name is **PersonComponent**

```
    var personAssembly = typeof(PersonComponent.Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var personEmbeddedFileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(
        personAssembly,
        "PersonComponent.wwwroot"
    );
```

Then you have to use this file provider in **UserStaticFiles** call

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = personEmbeddedFileProvider
});
```

Optionaly you can use an alternative content request path, so you can get your local and external resources using a different URL.
To do this just fill `RequestPath` variable when creating `StaticFileOptions`

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = personEmbeddedFileProvider,
    RequestPath = new PathString("/external")
});
```

Comment: What's the name of the static folder of the external assembly PersonComponent? ´\wwwroot´ or ´\external´

Comment: The folder's name is **wwwroot**.
**external** is a path string that you should use to avoid collisions in case you have static file with same name in different projects.
For example, if you have style.css in your site project and also in PersonComponent you shoud access the first one using **http://localhost/style.css** and the second using the path string **http://localhost/external/style.css**