# How can I embed an image in swagger documentation using swagger-ui?

Tags: markdown, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm trying to include an image in the `description` field of the `info` section of my swagger, which is displayed with Swagger-UI.  So far I've tried GFM:

```
...
  "info": {
    "description": "![alt text][/static/img/image.png]"
  }
...
```

and plain old HTML:

```
...
  "info": {
    "description": "<img alt=\"alt text\" src=\"/static/img/image.png\">"
  }
...
```

But both of these just render the string as given and don't display the image.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Depending on your toolset you can try the CSS approach from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62817980/8607180

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, replace

```
![alt text][/static/img/image.png]
```

with

```
![alt text](/static/img/image.png)
```

Note the image path is denoted with parentheses `()` instead of square brackets `[]`.

See also [How to format descriptions with Markdown in OpenAPI / Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39929108/113116).